# How can I pass my own variables between functions tied to action hooks in wordpress plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, parameter-passing, hook

I am writing a Wordpress plugin in PHP and I want to be able to use a variable that is not provided in the action hook (of other separate) plugin. I want to pass a variable from one hook to another.

These functions are in my functions.php file (not the theme functions file).

I cannot nest the action hooks because they happen at different times, specifically, the one with the variable happens after the one with where I want it.

I don't think I can use a closure because the variable is inside another hook.

I can't use a class because if I set the class in action 1 then it's not in scope in action 2 and I need to make a new one.

I could use a global or access the DB but I feel like there should be a better way than either of those.

action 1 - my plugin

```
function foo($level){
  do stuff
}
add_action('change-membership', 'foo');
```

action 2 - my plugin

```
function bar(){
  if($level==0){
    do stuff
  }
}
add_action('put-in-checkout-text', 'bar');
```

Other devs plugin

```
do_action('change_membership', $level);

// a little later
do_action('put_in_checkout_text');
```

$levels exists at the time I want it - but there is no action hook at that point to grab it.

Comment: Unless you are the developer that’s writing the plugin that has the “change membership” hook I suspect that you can do that since the hooks are practically events that triggers your function once it has been raised.So the first function will normally run in a different scope than the other function.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you have something like this:

```
// Plugin 2, the plugin you are writing.
do_action('put_in_checkout'); // --> bar()

// Plugin 1, another author's plugin
$level = "definition of level";
do_action('change_membership', $level); // --> foo($level)
```

You say you need to access to `$level` before the `change_membership` action happens, so `$level` may not be defined at that time. Even if it was, it may be in a scope not reachable from  `put_in_checkout` handler functions.
Just in case, check if plugin 2 instanciates a global variable where you have access to the value of `$level`. Otherwise, you need to take it from the database (if it is stored there) or generate it somehow.

Comment: Although slightly misinterpreted my question, you still provided me with an answer. I didn't know I could use globals from other plugins like this... I have been avoiding  globals like people suggest, but it seems to me to be inevitable, useful and commonplace. There is a global for the parameter I am looking for but it has not been given the value at that point after all. But thanks for showing me something new. I gave you +1 but it won't show sorry.

Comment: No problem Joz. I'm glad it helped you. When a global variable is defined in the global scope of a plugin, it remains global for the hole application. Because of possible name collision issues,it is recommended to avoid them if possible. But it is always necessary to define either a class or a function in the global scope to make a plugin.